# How to make back button return to the system Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a small app there is 3 seconds intro page, then the content page. When I push back button I go back to the intro screen, but I think I should go back to the system. How to do it?

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.ServiceModel.Syndication;
using System.Xml;
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;

namespace RSS {
    public partial class FeedPage : PhoneApplicationPage {
        public FeedPage() {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(PhonePage1_Loaded);
        }
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) {
            clearBackStack();
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }

        void clearBackStack() {
            while (this.NavigationService.BackStack.Any()) {
                this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
            }
        }

        void PhonePage1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
         //   clearBackStack();
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenReadCompleted);
            wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://www.carmagazine.co.uk/Shared/Handlers/RssHandler.ashx?&N=190&Ns=P_Publication_Date|1&?"));
        }
        void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e) {
            SyndicationFeed feed;
            try {
                using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(e.Result)) {
                    feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
                    lista.ItemsSource = feed.Items;
                }
            } catch (WebException we) { MessageBox.Show("Internet connection is down.");}
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) {

            WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
            String url = (String)((Button)sender).Tag;
            webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri(url);
            webBrowserTask.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should clear the BackStack in the `OnNavigateTo` method of your content page

```
while (this.NavigationService.BackStack.Any())
{
   this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
}
```

Comment: Is it against Microsoft rules? It is the first call at PhonePage1_Loaded

Comment: @RobertKilar the OnNavigatedTo method is a better place to put it in. It is not against the rules. It just makes your app quit when pressing the back button on your content page and it is ok

Answer (score 0):

The following code is the best practice for the back button key press.

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        while (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
            NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();

        base.OnBackKeyPress(e);

    }
```

This ensures that your application will exit and return to the main screen on pressing the BackKey.